# Missing Permissions discord.js V13

Tags: permissions, discord.js

it's me again, with another new problem!
I'm wanting to make a charge command where you use the menu, but there was an error!

**Missing Permissions**

If you want to see what's going on, I'll say it's not in slash commands!
gamerole.js

```js
const { MessageActionRow, MessageSelectMenu, MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")

module.exports = {
  name: 'gamerole',
  description: "get gaming console roles",
  userPerms: ["ADMINISTRATOR"],
  run: async(client, message, args, prefix) => {
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("Gaming Console Roles")
    .setDescription("Get Or Remove Roles By Clicking On Options Given In menu, After Reclicking The Role Will Be Removed, The Bot Will Send DM Message That You Have Added/Removed Roles")
    
    const row = new MessageActionRow()
    .addComponents(
      new MessageSelectMenu()
      .setCustomId('gamerole')
      .setPlaceholder('Select To Add/Remove Roles')
      .addOptions([
        {
          label: 'XBOX Role',
          description: "Click To Add/Remove XBOX Roles",
          value: 'xbox',
        },
        {
          label: 'PlayStation Role',
          description: "Click To Add/Remove PlayStation Roles",
          value: 'playstation',
        },
        ]),
      );
      await message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed], components: [row]});
  }
}
```

After that I went into messageCreate to see if the problem was there!
messageCreate.js

```js
const db = require("quick.db");
const client = require("../index.js");
client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
  if(message.author.bot) return;
  if(!message.guild) return;
  //PER SERVER PREFIX
  let prefix = await client.config.prefix;
 //1 if (!message.content.startsWith(client.config.prefix)) return;

  if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
  if(!message.member) message.member = await message.guild.fetchMember(message);
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
  const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  
  if(cmd.length == 0 ) return;
  let command = client.commands.get(cmd);
  if(!command) command = client.commands.get(client.aliases.get(cmd));
  if(command) {
    //USER PERMS
    if(!message.member.permissions.has(command.userPerms || [])) return message.channel.send(`User Dont Have \`${command.userPerms || []}\` Permission`);
    //BOT PERMISSIONS
    if(!message.guild.me.permissions.has(command.clientPerms || [])) return message.channel.send(`Bot Missing \`${command.botPerms || []}\` Permission`);
  }
  //EXPORTS TO COMMAND
  if(command) command.run(client, message, args, prefix);
});
```

The error is as follows:

```json
DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions
at RequestHandler.execute (/home/runner/B
ot-beta/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/Requ
estHandler.js:350:13)
at processTicksAndRejections (node: intern
al/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async RequestHandler.push (/home/runne
r/Bot-beta/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/R
equestHandler.js:51:14)
at async TextChannel.send (/home/runner/B
ot-beta/node_modules/discord.js/src/structure
s/interfaces/TextBasedChannel.js:175:15) {
method: 'post',
path: '/channels/843914213242961940/message
I
code: 50013,
httpStatus: 403,
requestData: {
json: {
content: undefined,
tts: false,
nonce: undefined,
embeds: [Array],
components: [Array],
username: undefined,
avatar_url: undefined,
allowed_mentions: undefined,
flags: 0,
message_reference: [Object],
attachments: undefined,
sticker_ids: undefined
},
files: []
```

Comment: Is your bot has permissions on server? Did you check it?

Comment: Yes, but it could be because the channel is closed anyway